# Relevance Testing Boolean Error

Tags: boolean

I am trying to find the version of files within two system locations. I am using the QnA relevance Fixlet Debugger

```
      q: version of file "java.exe" of folder "c:\program files (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_74\bin" AND version of file "java.exe" of folder "c:\program files\java\jre1.8.0_74\bin" OR version of file "java.exe" of folder "c:\program files\java\jre1.8.0_77\bin" AND version of file "java.exe" of folder "c:\program files (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_77\bin"
```

I keep getting the error "A Boolean expression is required" but I'm not sure where I am missing park of the Boolean expression. My goal is to identify both versions (x86, x64) of java

Comment: Hey, version of file is not a boolean value. So, Will you be able to perform AND or OR operations on them. May be that's the reason for the error